# Grammar of wxw^r over the alphabet {a,b}

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

I'm trying to write a grammar for w being a nonempty word and z any word. That is, these are words that start with a nonempty word and end with its reverse. I've seen a very similar grammar before but it uses the alphabet {a,b}* rather than just {a,b}. Could anyone help me come up with this grammar or give me some advice that could lead me to it.

Comment: The alphabet of a (phrase-structure) grammar is usually finite by definition, are you sure that $\{a, b\}^*$ was used as the alphabet ?